# Membership, Roles and Profile Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I´ve been reading a lot about membership providers, roles and profiles in asp.net but I cannot find what I´m looking for. I would like to know if anyone can point me a complete project - or blog post with step by step otherwise - that extends membership provider storing profiles in database as an extra table.

As far I checked default membership provider stores profiles in a way that most of the people express its concerns, mainly regarding to performance of that solution.

Consequently I would like to use membership generated by aspnet_regsql.exe to use SQL Server providers in ASP.NET with an extension using profiles in a database table -like user or customer -with all its details: name, company, address, etc...

Any addition like password retrieval already incorporated, user management etc. will be greatly appreciated.

Finally, if this is not available... could anyone shed some light of why MS team never developed a full solution for managing website security (users, roles, password retrieval, email confirmation of account, profiles stored in a way that all the people dont talk about performance and more)...

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own Profile provider and take over control of how your data is stored. There are several articles popping up on google if you search for "custom profile provider". 
This is one is good enough for a start :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163457.aspx

In terms of your question about performance etc. You ApplicationServices is a framework that is an option. You don't have to use that. In my option there is no way that you can build a generic mechanism of equal complexity to the AppServices that would be performing great in every setup. Each application is different, operating environment is different, requirements are different. Asp.Net gives you bunch of tools you can utilize and sample implementation. What you will do with it is up to you. You're the architect and it's your resposibility to design the application scructure so it performs the way you need it to.

Comment: thank you @torm, I´m surprised that I cannot find any implementation already developed with those functionalities. The closest development is membership kit by troy goodle but its the only one. brgds